# Find / Edit the order details meta text on WooCommerce emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, translation

I'm trying to translate the customer emails into Chinese but I can't find these anywhere in the Source code:

I've been able to find everything else and I think these are also hardcoded but I can't find them in the code.

[image]

This is in my `email-order-details.php` file:

```
<?php
$totals = $order->get_order_item_totals();

if ( $totals ) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
        $i++;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['label'] ); ?></th>
            <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['value'] ); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
if ( $order->get_customer_note() ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Note:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wptexturize( $order->get_customer_note() ) ); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
```

But I can't see where I can change the following:

- Subtotal:
- Discount:
- Shipping:
- Payment Method:
- Total:
- Taxes:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating the string via a built-in WordPress filter called [`gettext`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/) would probably be the better method to use, especially as the translation should then be site wide and not only on the email, example below:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_custom_string_translation', 999, 3 );
function my_custom_string_translation( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
    $translated = str_ireplace( 'Subtotal',       'Your translation here.', $translated );
    $translated = str_ireplace( 'Discount',       'Your translation here.', $translated );
    $translated = str_ireplace( 'Shipping',       'Your translation here.', $translated );
    $translated = str_ireplace( 'Payment Method', 'Your translation here.', $translated );
    $translated = str_ireplace( 'Total',          'Your translation here.', $translated );
    return $translated;
}
```

You can put the code above inside your `functions.php` or a custom plugin file.

Comment: Thanks that's very useful to have. Worked great.